# Select third element in the first row (webdriver.io and javascript) TypeError: tables.$ is not a function error

Tags: javascript, testing, html-table, cucumber, webdriver-io

I am using cucumber, webdriver.io and javascript and must select the third element in the first row. The table element keeps changing but will always begin with "__table" so I incorporated that into my code. There is one table present on my webpage and I tried to use a for loop to select the first table but the code within the for loop is not executing. When I remove the for loop I get a TypeError: tables.$ is not a function error. Here is the current state of my code. How can I modify the code to get it to run?

```
When("the user selects the customer from the results", async function () {
  // Implementation for selecting the customer from the results

  const tables = await $$('table[id^="__tables"]');
  console.log('Tables:', tables);
  for (const table of tables) {
    // Your code to interact with each table
    const firstRow = await table.$('tr');
    const thirdCell = await firstRow.$$('td')[2]; // Index 2 for the third cell
    const text = await thirdCell.getText();
    console.log('Cell text', text);
    await thirdCell.waitForClickable();
    await thirdCell.click()
  }
});
```

I tried the following solution to achieve my goal

```
When("the user selects the customer from the results", async function () {
  // Implementation for selecting the customer from the results

  const tables = await $$('table[id^="__tables"]');
  console.log('Tables:', tables);

  // Assuming you want to interact with the first table found
  const targetTable = tables[0];

  // Locate the first row in the table
  const firstRow = await targetTable.$('tr');

  // Locate the third cell (td) in the first row
  const thirdCell = await firstRow.$$('td')[2]; // Index 2 for the third cell

  // Perform actions on the selected cell
  await thirdCell.click();

});
```

But I get the following error

```
[0-0] Error in "0: And the user selects the customer from the results"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript try to implicitly add types for each line, or additionally on each line try to print to console something(text, length, isExist) to understand whats going on, or try to use debugging.

```
// Implementation for selecting the customer from the results
const tables: WebdriverIO.ElementArray = await $$('table[id^="__tables"]');
console.log('Tables:', tables);

// Assuming you want to interact with the first table found
const targetTable: WebdriverIO.Element = tables[0];

// Locate the first row in the table
const firstRow: WebdriverIO.Element = await targetTable.$('tr');

// Locate the third cell (td) in the first row
const thirdCell: WebdriverIO.Element = await firstRow.$$('td')[2]; // Index 2 for the third cell

// Perform actions on the selected cell
await thirdCell.click();
```